# Dynamically Modifying Column Names at Query Times in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table with columns `foo` and `bar`. I want to run a `SELECT *` on the table and have the result's columns suffixed by `"baz"`, i.e. the resulting set will have `foo_baz` and `bar_baz` columns.
The **transformation** **function** (suffix by "baz") is **known a-priori** (and will be built into the query), but the **column-set** of the table are **unknown**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below

```
execute immediate (
  select 'select ' || string_agg(col || ' as ' || col || '_baz', ', ') || ' from `project.dataset.table`'
  from (
    select regexp_extract_all(to_json_string(t), r'"(.*?)":') cols
    from `project.dataset.table` t limit 1
  ) t, t.cols col 
)
```

for example  - if applied to data as below

[image]

the output will be

[image]

Comment: Sorry, no. Hardcoded them. It's in the backlog.

Comment: The inner regex query doesn't work if there are string columns

Comment: It matches the beginning of a column's value (starting after a `"` to the end of the next column's name.

Comment: it is quite simple to adjust query for this - have you tried?

Comment: `r'"([^"]*?)":'`

Comment: It answers the question but I can't use it to create views or nest in any other queries. Tried `WITH`, `CREATE VIEW` and `SELECT FROM`.

Comment: consider also voting up the answer if it helped!. As of `view` - i don't see any mentioning of view in your original question so you might want to post new question